# connection between Salesforce and Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, journeybuilder

I made the connection between Salesforce Partner Dev Edition and Marketing Cloud. We also made the test connection , and it's works.

Now I'm trying to use the web to lead form (with some standard fields as: email, name, last, city, gender etc...). 
I want to read this leads into Marketing Cloud, and i also what to push a email to all the gender "male" for example.

Into the journey builder , i'm using "entry event" = salesforce data -> " Define Entry Source"= Salesforce data -> DEFINE EVENT RULES and here I'm stuck. Which kind of values I need to use? I need to filter my data? searching Gender =Male?

After that I also created an Email notification only for the men, I saw the area "Subscriber Management" and Publication List=All subscribers. What does it means? I'm going to send to everyone my test email?

Answer (score 2):

To filter the data coming into the journey, you would set the entry criteria on your event source (data extension)

> GENDER is equal to MALE

The publication list records the "subscription status" of each subscriber. Using the all subscriber tells Journey Builder to check against the all subscriber list to see if the contact is still opted into receiving email. If you maintain different publication lists, you can use them (eg. Different lines of communication for which the subscriber has opted in to)

**References:**

- [All Susbscribers List](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/all_subscribers_list/)
- [Publication Lists](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/publication_lists/)
- [Suppression Lists](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/)

**UPDATE**

From the comments, I gather the end goal of the journey is to send messages to only male participants.

You can do this the following ways:

1. Create a filtered data extension containing only "Male" and use that as your entry event.
2. Set the "Entry Criteria" on your event source in Journey Builder to

> GENDER is equal to Male

3. Use an SQL Activity to create a new data extension with only "Male" subscribers, then use this as your entry source.
4. Use an exclusion script in your Email Send activity.

I vote for number 2 as the "path of least resistance.

**UPDATE**

When using web to lead, your best best is to use the [Salesforce Data Event](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/selecting_an_entry_event_for_an_interaction/) as your entry source. To admit only "Male" subscribers, create a filter on the lead object and set it to "Male".

Comment: Hi Data_kid thanks for your help, I'm trying to import the data with Salesforce data event, And also I don't have the entry event configured, so I'm trying to use the filters.  The second step is dedicated  to the Event used, but which Event I can use? here I can only find events for push notification, predictive intelligence etc...thanks